# File Read, TCP Message not received

Tags: c, tcp

Trying to read a file in blocks and send each of those blocks over a TCP connection. When the read/send loop is complete, I send a confirmation message. Any time my file is larger than one block, which is almost always, the confirmation message never arrives. Can't tell if that is because it didn't get sent or just not received. It appears it was sent but I can't be sure. For small files, this works just fine. The file itself is sent correctly in all cases, but I need this confirmation message to send, too.

Can anyone see why this might be happening?

```
                int header_size = sizeof("file,,") + sizeof(int);
                int bytes_remaining, filesize;
                fseek(fp1, 0L, SEEK_END);
                filesize = bytes_remaining = ftell(fd);
                fseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_SET);

                int bytes_to_read;

                if ( (BUFFSIZE - header_size ) < bytes_remaining) {
                    bytes_to_read = BUFFSIZE - header_size;
                } else {
                    bytes_to_read = bytes_remaining;
                }

                while (bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, bytes_to_read, fd) > 0) {

                    sprintf(message, "file,%d,%s", bytes_to_read, buffer);
                    send(sd, message, bytes_to_read + header_size, 0);

                    bytes_remaining -= bytes_to_read;

                    if ( (BUFFSIZE - header_size) < bytes_remaining) {
                        bytes_to_read = BUFFSIZE - header_size;
                    } else {
                        bytes_to_read = bytes_remaining;
                    }

                    bzero(buffer, BUFFSIZE);
                }

                // send confirmation message
                bzero(buf, 256);
                sprintf(buf, "send_complete");
                send(sd, buf, 256, 0);
                fprintf(stdout, "complete: %s\n", buf);
```

Comment: Did you check the return value of send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`send()`, just as `write()` or `fwrite` doesn't guarantee that all data is consumed.
You must check the return value from `send()` for how many bytes was actually sent.

I'm guessing that you miss the confirmation message because the TCP output buffer is full at that point.